# Is it possible that my Dist folder generated by Gulp contains a vulnerability found in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I'm new to Gulp, and it's hard for me to read the `gulpfile.js` file.

**Here is my `devDependencies` in `package.json`:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    ...
  },
```

**A dependency of `gulp-cssnano` contains 2 vulnerabilities (that I cannot fix):**

```
                         === npm audit security report ===

                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Moderate        Denial of Service

  Package         js-yaml

  Patched in      >=3.13.0

  Dependency of   gulp-cssnano [dev]

  Path            gulp-cssnano > cssnano > postcss-svgo > svgo > js-yaml

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/788


  High            Code Injection

  Package         js-yaml

  Patched in      >=3.13.1

  Dependency of   gulp-cssnano [dev]

  Path            gulp-cssnano > cssnano > postcss-svgo > svgo > js-yaml

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/813

found 2 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 1 high) in 16904 scanned packages
  2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

**Here is my `gulpfile.js` file:**

```
//
// Gulpfile
//

"use strict";

...

const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

...

//
// CSS minifier - merges and minifies the below given list of Space libraries into one theme.min.css
//

function minCSS() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      './assets/css/theme.css',
    ])
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/css/'));
}
```

I won't use the `node_modules`' folder in production environment but the `dist` folder generated by `gulpfile.js`.

Will the `dist` folder contain the vulnerabilities of the related vulnerabilities in `devDependencies` because I see `const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano')` and `.pipe(cssnano())` in `gulpfile.js` which generates the `dist folder` with the help of the `gulp dist` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the dist folder contain the vulnerabilities of the related vulnerabilities in devDependencies

No, it won't.

The vulnerabilities are in files required by the `gulp-cssnano` package, not in its generated output (i.e. the contents of the `dist` folder). These vulnerable files reside in the `node_modules` folder and in your case, they won't touch the production environment, so you should be good to go.

Hooowever, I noticed that the `gulp-cssnano` package has been archived by its owner on GitHub and marked as deprecated, so you should probably look for an alternative.

Comment: "Hooowever, I noticed that the gulp-cssnano package has been archived by its owner on GitHub and marked as deprecated, so you should probably look for an alternative." Thank you for the info :).

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :)